# mathsf font in both text and math

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I want to define a `\newcommand` that produces the same font in both text and math modes. For example,

```
\newcommand{\abc}[1]{???#1}
```

Then

```
\abc{varName} is blah blah blah

$ \abc{varName} = 4 $
```

I want **varName** to have the same font in both cases, ideally the same as `\mathsf` font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something that is effectively the same as using `\ensuremath`: Just ask if `LaTeX` is in math - mode (`\ifmmode`) and then use `\mathsf` or switch temporarily to math-mode and apply `\mathsf` then.

By the way `\textsf` works both in `math` and `text` mode anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\abc}[1]{%
  \ifmmode
  \mathsf{#1}%
  \else
  $\mathsf{#1}$%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\LARGE 
\abc{varName} is blah blah blah

$ \abc{varName} = 4 $

\begin{equation}
\abc{Hello} = 7
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, did not know about \ifmmode

Answer (score 4):

The `\ensuremath` command allows things from math mode to be used in both text mode and math mode. Thus, you can write your command like this.

```
\newcommand{\abc}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
```

Comment: What document class or packages are you using?

Comment: @Z0lenDer: `\ensuremath` is a LaTeX core command, it should work always (unless some package disables it ;-))

Comment: Checked again and it worked, probably did not see the font clearly the first time! Anyway thanks to both of you Arun and Christian :)